# React-Native: Share file

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I'm a web developer (React) and I'm facing in my first react-native App. The context is an app where user can create and configure recipes. The app is without any type of authentication (at the moment). Now I would like to implement a Share functionality to share a recipe through social and messaging apps. The user clicking in the shared content open the app and can view the recipe.

At the moment I used react-native-fs and react-native-share to create and share a file (json or txt). Now I have problem to open app clicking the file shared. I saw some example of DeepLink but all the example involves only web resources. There are any way to use deeplink with file?

There are better pattern to achieve my objective? (considering the use case where there are only Application without any backend and server)

Thanks in advance.